# Mean of the product of two edges of a random triangle

Tags: geometry, average

Hey:) Consider 3 points in 3D space that create a triangle with edges denoted with X,Y and Z. Let's say the points' locations are distributed according to an unknown distribution (maybe the pdf doesn't matter). My question is how am I able to find the E[XY] because as far as I know X and Y are obviously dependent. Is any case where the dependence between X and Y is almost negligible so as to approximate E[XY] as E[X]E[Y]? Running simulations I found that when the XYZ angle takes small values the approximation holds.

Comment: Without loss of generality, the first point is the intersection of $X$ and $Y$. The other two points, chosen independently, determine the length of these edges. $X$ and $Y$ are not dependent.

Comment: How's that possible? I mean, based on law of cosines X and Y are related with each other. I'm confused

Comment: The law of cosines can only be applied if you know the angle between two known edges or the length of the third edge. Neither of these can be determined from $X$ and $Y$

Comment: Yeah but it clearly shows the dependence between X and Y. Also, E[XY]=E[X]E[Y] doesn't hold in experiments..

Comment: It is possible that your simulations do not accurately represent the stated conditions. The result may also depend on the distribution of the points. If all three points are chosen uniformly within a unit cube, then $E[XY]\neq E[X]E[Y]$ because $X$ and $Y$, though independent, are both dependent on the location of their common endpoint. If that common point is fixed (at the origin, for instance) with the other two points iid, then $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$ does hold true.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback:) Unfortunately their common endpoint is not fixed but distributed according to a Poisson Point Process.. The only fixed point is one of the rest two, at the origin. So, we agree that X and Y are dependent in this case.  Do you know if there is something I can do to minimize this dependency and approximately set E[XY]=E[X]E[Y] given that the points are 3D? Can you also suggest me anything to read regarding your last comment?